# Text alignment in textbox in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have developed SSRS report where in When Text inside textbox is longer than length of the textbox, it is shifting to next line.But while shifting, it is missing the alignment.
For E.g. : 
 Queue Modification
 Number

Queue Modification
Number

I have already tried alignment option in textbox properties. There is one more property'SpaceBefore' but I am not sure how it works since it is just having Expression as value.

Comment: Can you post a picture? It sounds like you may be able to use the cell padding property to fix it if it refuses to align.

Comment: u're right but Cell Padding property is not getting applicable whenever there is multiline Text.Any idea ? (Note: Due to Access restrictions I can not take screenshot of it.)

Comment: Did that help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ListLevel or Padding properties on your textbox to change the indent. They do the same thing, but padding gives you more control over how large a space you want to indent.

Here's an example from a report I made that uses the lookupset function to return multiple lines. In this picture, the second row of the tablix returns multiple lines.

[image: NoAlignment]

Here's that same report with the listlevel property = 2 for ItemNumber and =3 for description.

[image]

Just select the textbox you want to update, click on properties and change the cell padding or the listlevel to get the indent you want. **You may not be able to highlight several textboxes at once to do this and may have to modify each individually.** (Annoying, I know!)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set direction rtl or ltr when you add textbox.